# Why don't I see direct links for posts (on main or meta)?

Tags: support, design

On every other Stack Exchange site I see "share" links under questions and answers, which provide access to a short, direct URL.  I don't see those links here, leading me to manually construct a URL to reference another answer [here](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/a/106) (see what I did there?).

Is the "share" link disabled on private betas because they are, after all, private, and we'll get this when the public beta starts?  So, in the meantime, if we want to reference a specific answer we should just roll our own?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this is intended behavior for private betas, I noticed the same in the last private beta I was a part of.

As Monica alluded to, if you want a workaround (yeah! fight the power!), referencing your answers by hand editing the url will still work:

> https://pets.stackexchange.com/a/{ANSWER ID}

The answer id can be obtained from the url for the edit page for the post. Example: https://pets.stackexchange.com/a/313

Comment: Yup, that's how I created the answer links I've used.

Comment: @Monica oops, I somehow missed that in your question. My mistake!