# Should we have questions based on other questions?

Tags: discussion, on-topic, questions

I saw https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/723/is-it-safe-for-me-to-use-human-medication-on-my-pet that is like a response to two other questions. Although the OP already answered it, I feel we don't need this types of question.

What does community feel about this?

Comment: I think we don't need to raise question bank just by duplicating existing one by just changing the pet from dog to cat or any other animal.

Comment: I suggest you use another post as an example, this Q is already addressed in detail here http://meta.pets.stackexchange.com/questions/348/human-medications-on-pets

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, in certain circumstances when one question leads to another question which

1. also qualifies for the site as a valid question
2. shouldn't be answered within the context of the parent question.

As an existing example for Pets.SE, see

- Parent: [Why is my dog drinking his pee after he urinates inside?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/473/why-is-my-dog-drinking-his-pee-when-he-urinates-inside)
- Derived Child: [How should I correct my dog when I catch him drinking his urine?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/496/how-should-i-correct-my-dog-when-i-catch-him-drinking-his-urine)

Of note, the Derived Child was created at the inferred request of a solution provider commenting in the Parent.

Comment: Now why was that downvoted? I seriously can't keep up with the logic. +1

Comment: I think we need a meta for meta to take issues like this to O.o

Comment: Sometimes I put too much faith in the intelligence of others to draw their own conclusions.  Apparently people must be coddled.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with having questions based on other questions. Providing, each question is self contained. Providing linked questions (and answers) is a useful process for enabling people to navigate the website.

Josh's examples are good to provide illustration of this.

The example question you gave is not useful for the purposes of this discussion, as it is being discussed in length in two other meta posts, on three posts in beta and within chat. If the purpose of the question is to address questions like these, I suggest this question be closed as a dup.

[Human medications on pets](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/348/human-medications-on-pets)

[When are medical questions on-topic?](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105/when-are-medical-questions-on-topic)

http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10964/conversation/human-medicine-for-dogs