# How can we improve the [care] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

We have a tag for [care](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/care)...

The tag wiki reads:

> For questions relating to the general care of a pet, in maintaining an optimum environment and lifestyle for a pet. For issues that may overlap several specific needs and comfort of a pet.
>
> For questions relating to the general care of a pet, in maintaining an optimum environment and lifestyle for a pet. Issues regarding the comfort and needs of a pet, with regard to lighting, heating, sleeping, supervision; questions that may not be specifically related any topic like health or feeding as a few examples.

Here are a couple examples of what questions are using the tag:

[How can I get a guppy out from beneath an under gravel filter?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/7840/how-can-i-get-a-guppy-out-from-beneath-an-under-gravel-filter)

[What is the best cold-water fish to control a baby guppy population?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/7839/what-is-the-best-cold-water-fish-to-control-a-baby-guppy-population)

[How much space do cats need?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/7709/how-much-space-do-cats-need)

[Is it possible to keep two small Goldfish in a 2.5 gallon (10 litres) tank?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/7647/is-it-possible-to-keep-two-small-goldfish-in-a-2-5-gallon-tank)

[My rabbit just had babies and isn’t feeding them](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/7418/my-rabbit-just-had-babies-and-isn-t-feeding-them)

[My rabbit just had babies and they are dying. What can I do?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/7417/my-rabbit-just-had-babies-and-they-are-dying-what-can-i-do)

[Why is it important to clean a tortoise's shell?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/7411/why-is-it-important-to-clean-a-tortoises-shell)

[Holding Rabbit by the scruff of her neck](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/7284/holding-rabbit-by-the-scruff-of-her-neck)

https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/7213/what-should-i-do-when-my-bird-starts-losing-feathers

And it keeps going as there are 85 questions using the tag.

It seems to me like right now the tag is being used as a generic "I don't know what tag to use" tag, which in my opinion is bad but maybe I'm wrong.

1. Is this tag being used properly?
2. Is there something we could do to make it more clear what it's supposed to be used for?
3. Should we just get rid of it?

What do you think?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I vote for "just get rid of it".  It's hard to see a unifying theme to these questions.  If there are questions on that list that would be left untagged, then that means we need to consider other tags -- but *this* one does not seem helpful.

I don't know if there's a way to check tag history, but I suspect that this tag was created during the early days of the private beta, when the tag set was still very much unformed.  Early tags often need to be refactored, and this probably isn't the only one.

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, [I feel similarly](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/660/is-the-health-tag-too-broad) about [health](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/health).

My general rule of thumb for tagging is that each question should have at least 2 tags, one to describe the applicable species and one to describe the subject of the problem. When we don't have a specific tag for a certain problem, the general [health](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/health) or [care](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/care) end up being used ([behavior](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/behavior) may also belong in this list).

Over time, as we start getting more repetitive problems we can start adding tags for issues that we see more than once (my rule of thumb has been about 5 questions). For example, I added [upper-respiratory-disease](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/upper-respiratory-disease) since FHV-1/feline herpes is endemic in the rescued cat population. At this point, the general tag can/should be removed.

Answer (score 2):

Care is too broad and is better served with more case-specific tags, many of which are mentioned as part of the all-encompassing care tag description.

Delete it.