# PSA: I'm starting the process of removing the tag [care]

Tags: discussion, tags, retagging

Based on the previous discussion that happend last week: [How can we improve the [care] tag?](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2041/how-can-we-improve-the-care-tag)

It sounds to me like the general feeling towards the tag: [care](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/care) is that it's pretty useless and should be removed instead of changed. So I'm beginning the process of removing the tag from questions.

There are currently about 75 questions using the tag. I'll try not to re-tag them in too large of batches so that it doesn't disrupt the site too much.

Feel free to chip in if you feel the inclination to, or shout at me to stop if you disagree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with replacing / removing [care](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/care) by a non-admin is that it bubbles the questions formerly tagged "care" to the top.

Since no admin has volunteered, I say go for it and let sorting be sorting.